# @PersistenceContext cannot find my table but EntityManagerFactory does

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to get a better understanding at how JPA works. First I tried this :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Optional<User> checkCredentials(String login, String password) {
        try {
            TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.checkCredentials", User.class);
            query.setParameter("login", login);
            query.setParameter("password", password);

            return Optional.of(query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException | NoResultException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
```

But my table USERS is not found. It's working perfectly whith this:

```
public Optional<User> checkCredentials(String login, String password) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPU");
        EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

        try {
            TypedQuery<User> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.checkCredentials", User.class);
            query.setParameter("login", login);
            query.setParameter("password", password);

            return Optional.of(query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException | NoResultException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
  <persistence-unit name="myPU">
    <class>fr.tzoreol.myapp.entities.Game</class>
    <class>fr.tzoreol.myapp.entities.League</class>
    <class>fr.tzoreol.myapp.entities.Team</class>
    <class>fr.tzoreol.myapp.entities.User</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="************"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Anyone can explain why and what is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to debug more to figure out what is different in the two environments, but it'll come down to class loaders. Using @PersistenceContext has the container control the persistence context, and define everything within it, and giving class loaders to the JPA provider to handle the rest. In the later case, your JPA provider is required to do so based on what is on hand when createEntityManagerFactory is called.My guess isn't that the class isn't found, but that the one used to load the EM originally isn't the one used to load the user class, so it doesn't recognize it as an entity.